# Why BAC company has "Gross Profit" reported every day?

Tags: trading, accounting, financial-statements

I was looking into performance of BAC (Bank Of America Corp) and noticed very strange thing - it reports "Gross Profit" almost every day. See attached image and [the link](https://www.gurufocus.com/chart/BAC?fp=q#&serie=,,id:Gross_Profit,s:NYSE:BAC).

[image]

Why is it so, is BAC a special company that fills financial reports differently, usually companies fill it just 4 times a year.

For example, below is how the same graph looks like for AMD, it has only 3 points because there are only 3 quarterly reports has been filled so far this year.

[image]

Comment: Maybe **banks** have more stringent reporting requirements than do semiconductor companies.  Examine other banks to see if they too report frequently.

Comment: Yea, could be the case, I was suspecting something like that but would like to know the better answer, JPM also has similar reporting

Comment: Just a note - in your question you refer to 'gross revenue', but the image states 'gross profit'. These are different things; gross revenue refers to, essentially, the initial sales value of a company's product. In this case, for a bank it might mean interest on their loans + bank fees. Gross profit typically has some deductions to reduce the revenue, typically just Cost of Goods Sold, which is the immediate cost of creating each dollar of that gross revenue. In this case, for a bank it might mean their *own* paid interest on the money they borrow, and some immediate costs associated with fees